# How to add padding to Qt Menu Items for Width?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, styles

Basically I am using Qt Menu by adding actions with Shortcuts. They look fine when the menu shows up.

But I want to add more spacing between the action item text and its shortcut. Is this possible? I couldn't find any function to do this.

setMinimumWidth works but I need add on top of the dynamic width computed by Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the complex way QMenu computes its size, using `setMinimumWidth()` is not a reliable option: once that size is set, there's no way to unset it, and the `sizeHint()` will always use that minimum.

There are two possible workarounds for that, though.

### Force layouting of the menu

This is a bit hacky and dirty, and might not work well in all situations. The trick is to force layouting again by adding a "fake" action that will be instantly removed.

You can do this by connecting specific functions to the `aboutToShow` and `aboutToHide` signals:

```py
def resizeMenu(menu):
    for action in menu.actions():
        if action.shortcut():
            menu.setMinimumWidth(menu.sizeHint().width() + 50)
            menu.removeAction(menu.addAction(''))
            break

def restoreMenu(menu):
    menu.setMinimumWidth(0)
    menu.removeAction(menu.addAction(''))


menu.aboutToShow.connect(lambda: resizeMenu(menu))
menu.aboutToHide.connect(lambda: restoreMenu(menu))
```

You could also install an event filter on the application so that it will work for all menus:

```py
class MenuWatcher(QtCore.QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if isinstance(obj, QtWidgets.QMenu):
            if event.type() == event.Show:
                for action in obj.actions():
                    if action.shortcut():
                        menu.setMinimumWidth(menu.sizeHint().width() + 50)
                        menu.removeAction(menu.addAction(''))
                        break
            elif event.type() == event.Hide:
                if menu.minimumWidth():
                    menu.setMinimumWidth(0)
                    menu.removeAction(menu.addAction(''))
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

# ...
watcher = MenuWatcher()
app.installEventFilter(watcher)
```

### Using a QProxyStyle

By overriding the [`sizeFromContents()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#sizeFromContents) of a QProxyStyle we can check whether the option is a `CT_MenuItem`, and if it has a `tabWidth` (indicating that at least a *previous* action has a shortcut) or a `\t` in its `text` (meaning that it probably has a shortcut), we can add a specific width before returning the size provided by the default implementation:

```py
class ProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def sizeFromContents(self, ct, opt, size, widget=None):
        size = super().sizeFromContents(ct, opt, size, widget)
        if ct == self.CT_MenuItem and (opt.tabWidth or '\t' in opt.text):
            size.setWidth(size.width() + 50)
        return size

# ...
app.setStyle(ProxyStyle())
```